# How to deserialize an XML array with different type attributes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have this XML that I want to deserialize and later re-serialize:

```
<SecurityCustomizationData xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Security.Management" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <_x003C_CustomizationsForTypeList_x003E_k__BackingField>
    <BaseRepositoryCustomizations i:type="RepositoryCustomizationsOfAxSecurityRoleNcCATIYq">
    </BaseRepositoryCustomizations>
    <BaseRepositoryCustomizations i:type="RepositoryCustomizationsOfAxSecurityDutyNcCATIYq">
    </BaseRepositoryCustomizations>
    <BaseRepositoryCustomizations i:type="RepositoryCustomizationsOfAxSecurityPrivilegeNcCATIYq">
    </BaseRepositoryCustomizations>
  </_x003C_CustomizationsForTypeList_x003E_k__BackingField>
</SecurityCustomizationData>
```

There is more but to replicate the problem this suffices. I've tried the "Paste XML to Classes" approach but then the serializer cannot get over the type attributes `RepositoryCustomizationsOfAxSecurityRoleNcCATIYq` etc.

I've tried to write my own classes based on that code but then it won't even try to deserialize the innermost elements.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Security.Management")]
public class SecurityCustomizationData
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("<CustomizationsForTypeList>k__BackingField")]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(RoleRepoCust))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(DutyRepoCust))]
    [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(PrivilegeRepoCust))]
    public BaseRepositoryCustomizations[] CustomizationsForTypeListk__BackingField
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class BaseRepositoryCustomizations
{
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "RepositoryCustomizationsOfAxSecurityRoleNcCATIYq", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public class RoleRepoCust : BaseRepositoryCustomizations
{
}
[XmlType(TypeName = "RepositoryCustomizationsOfAxSecurityDutyNcCATIYq", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public class DutyRepoCust : BaseRepositoryCustomizations
{
}
[XmlType(TypeName = "RepositoryCustomizationsOfAxSecurityPrivilegeNcCATIYq", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
public class PrivilegeRepoCust : BaseRepositoryCustomizations
{
}
```

All examples I've found regarding XmlArrayItemAttribute use different element names to pick the right class. I've also tried to use just one class for the items but then I have the same problem as with the generated classes: the i:type attribute causes an error.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but the XML looks like DataContractSerializer-generated. May be you can just to use this serializer and all will be work out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Serg for this to work he still needs an appropriate class definition for DataContractSerializer return type. The serializer wont guess the type or build it dynamically.

Comment: You already created a class definition based on your xml. Just try to serialize an instance of it with DataContractSerializer and compare the output with your xml. You will see what prop names or other things need to be adjusted to get the "right" class definition. Then use it as @Serg suggested!

Comment: @cly I've looked into this DataContractSerializer but it doesn't work anybetter on the XML. It complains that it expects an element "SecurityCustomizationData" after 170 chars but gets an element "SecurityCustomizationData". I've tried using that serializer to create a file but it is missing the type specifier which is essential.

Comment: @Serg might have been wrong. Try XmlSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer. I tried to serialize your class candidate with XmlSerializer and the results are near to your xml. Reach this point then play with your class to learn which part produces which one in the xml output.